# What is this "overlay" in a MinGW g++ executable?

Tags: g++, size, executable

I have this C++ file:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::cout << "Hello world!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

After compiling with g++ I get a 913KiB big executable. I was astonished, because I thought g++ would be smart enough to not include any code or data not used by the program from the STL.

Next I used [UPX](http://upx.sourceforge.net/) with these settings: `upx --overlay=strip`. After this the executable size was reduced to `142KiB`, a reduction of 85% with no speed penalty (I tested this with more complex, mathematical programs).

According to the [upx man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/upx):

> An "overlay" means auxillary data atached after the logical end of an executable, and it often contains application specific data (this is a common practice to avoid an extra data file, though it would be better to use resource sections).

I couldn't find any info that was more specific and was left with the following questions:

#### - What exactly is this overlay?

#### - Is it safe to strip?

#### - If yes, why doesn't g++ do it, even with -Os?

Contextual information:

- Windows 7 Home Premium SP1 64 bit
- MinGW installed with [TDM-GCC](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/)
- g++ version 4.5.2
- Compiling with `g++ -Os test.cpp`

Comment: Note that TDM-GCC excels at incompatibility with the official/unpatched toolchains released by the MinGW(-w64) projects themselves. (different commandline options, incompatible ABI-breaking patches, etc...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-Os` optimises the generated code for size, it doesn't say anything about other non-code segments in the executable file.

Did you try the `-s` linker option to strip debug symbols, suggested [here](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Large_executables)?

Comment: This does bring the original executable down to 466KiB, but UPX can still bring that further down to 133KiB by stripping "overlay", so this doesn't really answer my question.

Comment: Are you sure UPX is *only* stripping overlay, or is it *also* doing whatever magical compression it usually does?

Comment: @Useless: Oh I'm such an idiot. The `-s` option actually accounts for the `--overlay=strip`, the rest is indeed compression. I'll accept this answer.

Comment: That UPX tool looks interesting though, so thanks for bringing it to my attention.